# How to accomplish something like Google Keep layout

Tags: javascript, html, css

In Google Keep, they have a couple columns (depending on your viewport width) of equal width notes that they arrange to make it not look uniform.

[image]

How can something like this be accomplished? I'm guessing they have specific breakpoints at certain widths, and after accounting for the padding and margins, they make the image match the desired width, and simply let the image height maintain the same aspect ratio.

It's just my guess; how would it be done?

Comment: Have you tried http://masonry.desandro.com/ ?

Comment: +1 @Champ, I was also going to suggest that. Its so good!

Comment: @Champ Haven't seen that before, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: This can be done with CSS only.

Answer (score 4):

A more simplistic solution might be to use the CSS column property, that way you can control the amount of columns in your breakpoints (also gutters).

Additionally it seems all together a good idea to me that if you can achieve the same effect without a bunch of explicit containers then you should. Obviously there are things to consider with flow that might make that decision for you. Hope this helps add to the above answer a bit.

```css
.container {
  -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
  column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-gap: .5rem; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-gap: .5rem; /* Firefox */
  column-gap: .5rem;

}
.note {
  width: calc(100% / 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="note" src="http://www.slate.com/content/dam/slate/blogs/bad_astronomy/2014/06/Ten%20Years%20at%20Saturn/cassini_ugarkovic_saturn.jpg.CROP.original-original.jpg">
  <img class="note" src="http://www.slate.com/content/dam/slate/blogs/bad_astronomy/2014/06/Ten%20Years%20at%20Saturn/cassini_iapetus_sidebyside.jpg.CROP.original-original.jpg">
  <img class="note" src="http://www.slate.com/content/dam/slate/blogs/bad_astronomy/2014/06/Ten%20Years%20at%20Saturn/cassini_mimas.jpg.CROP.original-original.jpg">
  <img class="note" src="http://www.slate.com/content/dam/slate/blogs/bad_astronomy/2014/06/Ten%20Years%20at%20Saturn/cassini_ugarkovic_saturn.jpg.CROP.original-original.jpg">
  <img class="note" src="http://www.slate.com/content/dam/slate/blogs/bad_astronomy/2014/06/Ten%20Years%20at%20Saturn/cassini_mimas.jpg.CROP.original-original.jpg">
  <img class="note" src="http://www.slate.com/content/dam/slate/blogs/bad_astronomy/2014/06/Ten%20Years%20at%20Saturn/cassini_iapetus_sidebyside.jpg.CROP.original-original.jpg">
  <img class="note" src="http://www.slate.com/content/dam/slate/blogs/bad_astronomy/2014/06/Ten%20Years%20at%20Saturn/cassini_iapetus_sidebyside.jpg.CROP.original-original.jpg">
  <img class="note" src="http://www.slate.com/content/dam/slate/blogs/bad_astronomy/2014/06/Ten%20Years%20at%20Saturn/cassini_ugarkovic_saturn.jpg.CROP.original-original.jpg">
  <img class="note" src="http://www.slate.com/content/dam/slate/blogs/bad_astronomy/2014/06/Ten%20Years%20at%20Saturn/cassini_mimas.jpg.CROP.original-original.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: With this solution, the imgs are stacked vertically, column by column. Usually, in layouts like this, users need to see the "latest news" (likely corresponding to the first tags in the HTML) in the first row.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a great example, but one thing you can do is use flex-box in columns.

```css
.note {
  max-width: 100px;
  margin: 5px 10px;
}
div.container {
   display: -webkit-flex;
   display: flex;
   -webkit-flex-direction: row;
   flex-direction: row;
   background-color: lightgray;
}
div.column {
   display: -webkit-flex;
   display: flex;
   -webkit-flex-direction: column;
   flex-direction: column;
   background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="column">
  <img class="note" src="http://www.slate.com/content/dam/slate/blogs/bad_astronomy/2014/06/Ten%20Years%20at%20Saturn/cassini_ugarkovic_saturn.jpg.CROP.original-original.jpg">
  <img class="note" src="http://www.slate.com/content/dam/slate/blogs/bad_astronomy/2014/06/Ten%20Years%20at%20Saturn/cassini_iapetus_sidebyside.jpg.CROP.original-original.jpg">
  <img class="note" src="http://www.slate.com/content/dam/slate/blogs/bad_astronomy/2014/06/Ten%20Years%20at%20Saturn/cassini_mimas.jpg.CROP.original-original.jpg">
</div>
<div class="column">
  <img class="note" src="http://www.slate.com/content/dam/slate/blogs/bad_astronomy/2014/06/Ten%20Years%20at%20Saturn/cassini_ugarkovic_saturn.jpg.CROP.original-original.jpg">
  <img class="note" src="http://www.slate.com/content/dam/slate/blogs/bad_astronomy/2014/06/Ten%20Years%20at%20Saturn/cassini_mimas.jpg.CROP.original-original.jpg">
  <img class="note" src="http://www.slate.com/content/dam/slate/blogs/bad_astronomy/2014/06/Ten%20Years%20at%20Saturn/cassini_iapetus_sidebyside.jpg.CROP.original-original.jpg">
</div>
<div class="column">
  <img class="note" src="http://www.slate.com/content/dam/slate/blogs/bad_astronomy/2014/06/Ten%20Years%20at%20Saturn/cassini_iapetus_sidebyside.jpg.CROP.original-original.jpg">
  <img class="note" src="http://www.slate.com/content/dam/slate/blogs/bad_astronomy/2014/06/Ten%20Years%20at%20Saturn/cassini_ugarkovic_saturn.jpg.CROP.original-original.jpg">
  <img class="note" src="http://www.slate.com/content/dam/slate/blogs/bad_astronomy/2014/06/Ten%20Years%20at%20Saturn/cassini_mimas.jpg.CROP.original-original.jpg">

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a redundant way of having the same result of column layout :)

Answer (score 2):

If you just want small-scale light-weight implementation, use [Minigrid](http://minigrid.js.org/)

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://npmcdn.com/minigrid@3.0.1/dist/minigrid.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <div class="cards">
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.card {
  width: 160px;
}


/* Anything bellow here isn't necessary, it's only for the demo */

.card {
  background-color: #F25D9C ; 
}

/* Set some height to cards */
.card:nth-child(1) {
  height: 240px;
}

.card:nth-child(2) {
  height: 190px;
}

.card:nth-child(3) {
  height: 210px;
}

.card:nth-child(4) {
  height: 230px;
}

.card:nth-child(5) {
  height: 180px;
}

.card:nth-child(6) {
  height: 200px;
}

body {
  background-color: #F9F7F7;
}

.cards {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1040px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Javascript:

```
(function(){
  var grid;
  function init() {
    grid = new Minigrid({
      container: '.cards',
      item: '.card',
      gutter: 12
    });
    grid.mount();
  }

  // mount
  function update() {
    grid.mount();
  }

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);
  window.addEventListener('resize', update);
})();
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/wamele/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

For my project I was using the [`react-masonry-css`](https://github.com/paulcollett/react-masonry-css#readme) cascading `grid layout` library,  that is fork of [`masonry project`](https://github.com/desandro/masonry). You can set up it in few mins. It works perfectly.

*P.s.* follow the guideline how to re-create the `Google Keep` UX with `react-masonry-css` [library](https://dev.to/shambhavijs/google-keep-lite-building-google-keep-clone-using-reactjs-4474)